# How to run multiple parallel suites in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

MainSuite.java

```js
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    TestSuite1.class,
    TestSuite2.class, 
    TestSuite3.class
})
public class MainSuite {
  private MainSuite() {}
}
```

and for each Test Suite there are classes that contains @Test

for Example

TestSuite1.java

```js
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    TestClass1.class
})

public class TestSuite1 {
  private TestSuite1() {}
  }
```

TestClass1.java

```js
@Test
public void test1(){}

@Test
public void test2() 
....
```

So my question is how to run TestSuite1, TestSuite2 & TestSuite3 in parallel using testNG.xml ???

Answer (score -1):

Running suites parallel in TestNG.xml is not allowed as per testng implementation. Have to use Maven or from command prompt.

in cmd, Like

```
  java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 3 testng1.xml testng2.xml testng3.xml
```

see here for more info http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running